# How do I find out who is voice chatting in TDU2?

Tags: pc, voice-chat, test-drive-unlimited-2

Test Drive Unlimited 2, while fun, is seriously marred by an immature player-base. Having to put up with a semi-constant stream of profanity is wearing me thin, to the point where I'm considering turning it off for good. But before I do that, is there a way to find out who's yelling at me at a given time? I'd much rather block/report them than turning voice chatting off completely.

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody knows/cares :(

Comment: On what platform are you playing?

Comment: PC. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: Ah, I really don't know for PC, haven't got the game (yet). On Xbox, it would have been easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility to mute a specific player.

You will have to turn voice off altogether :(

Comment: Well, that sucks. I guess I'll mute voice chatting, then, and that's it.